# create a folder with copied contents

Tags: php, directory, copy

what I want to do is when the user pushes a button, he/she creates a folder thats name is a random number. so far this is what I have:

```html
<form action="script.php" method="get">
  <input type="submit" value="Run me now!">
</form>
```

here is my php:

```html
<?php 
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) {
  $dir = opendir($src); 
  @mkdir($dst); 
  while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
      if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
         if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
             recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
         } 
         else { 
             copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
         } 
      } 
  } 
 closedir($dir); 
}
 
/* Source directory (can be an FTP address) */
$src = "./xe5";
 
/* Full path to the destination directory */
$dst = "./community";
 
recurse_copy($src,$dst);
?>
```

Comment: SO what is your question?

Comment: how would you go about generating folders with random names to fill